# backslash in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

In Matlab `x=A\b`; solves the linear system Ax=b. Is it possible to imitate the same in C++? Possible with operator overloading, but how to use \ instead of / in the following program?

```
friend Vector operator/(const Vector &b, const Matrix &A)
{   //BiCG Algorithm is used here. 
    int row=A.getrowdim();
    int col=A.getcoldim();
    Vector x(row,0.0);
    Vector r(row,0.0);
    Vector s(row,0.0);
    Vector u(row,0.0);
    Vector v(row,0.0);
    Vector w(row,0.0);
    Vector p(row,0.0);
    double rho0,beta,alpha,rho;
    Vector t(row,0.0);
    double norm;
    r=b-A*x;
    s=r;
    rho0=1;
    for(int k=1;k<M;k++)
    {
        rho=s*r;
        beta=rho/rho0;
        u=r+beta*u;
        w=s+beta*w;
        v=A*u;
        alpha=rho/(w*v);
        x=x+alpha*u;
        r=r-alpha*v;
        s=s-alpha*(Transpose(A)*w);
        norm=r.norm(2);
        cout<<"Step Number "<<k<<" xnorm "<<norm<<endl;
        if(norm<eps)
            break;
        rho0=rho;
    }
       return x;
}
```

Comment: Any decent C++ book, tutorial or class should have told you that you can't invent your own operators.

Comment: Yes. It does and I know. I would like to know if any hack around is available.

Comment: Give it a reasonable descriptive name like a normal function.

Comment: operator overloading has more downsides than one might expect. A good case for overloading an operator is when the semantics are natural and clear to everyone. As nothing else in C++ has a operator `\\`, your case is not one of them and then it is usually better to use a member function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You cannot overload `operator\` (mainly because it does not exist).

Give the operation a nice, clear, descriptive name like any other function.